How to make first row as the header while importing an excel (xlsm) file into SAS
I have a excel sheet (Xlsm) that I wanted to export , issue is that the first row is supposed to be the header. How do I replace the header with the first row while importing. Please not that I cannot make changes to the base file.
Data that I have
         A         B         C 
1      Name 1   Name 2     Name 3
2        2        4          66
3        3        5          6

Data that I need.
         Name 1        Name 2        Name 3
1             2          4               66   
2             3          5               6

I have used  DATAROW but its not working.

Are you exporting or importing? SAS does not write XLSM files.  It can write XLSX files.  I think it can read either, but test to be sure.

PROC IMPORT always takes the names from the first row of data (unless you tell it not to by using GETNAMES=NO; statement).
DATAROW option has no impact on where it looks for the names.
If the names are on the FIRST row then that is the default for where to find them so no additional options are needed.
If the names are on the second row then use the RANGE setting instead.  Set the range to start in the first column and second row.
Try this example:
filename xlsx temp;
proc export data=sashelp.class file=xlsx dbms=xlsx replace; 
run;
proc import file=xlsx dbms=xlsx out=want replace;
  range='$A2:';
run;

Here is a picture of what the XLSX file will look like:

And here is the picture of the SAS dataset that results when told to read starting with the second row.


Sorry, this did not help, also DATAROW option is supported for reading Excel files.

What does not work?  The example data you showed (assuming the A,B,C and 1,2,3 are column and row labels of the spreadsheet and not part of the data) does not require any extra options for PROC IMPORT as the default is to use the first row of data as the names.  Is the problem being caused by reading from an XLSM file instead of an XSLX file? Can you save the file as XLSX and see if SAS can read it?

Can you describe your problem better? i can't follow you whats failing here

To CREATE an Excel file from a SAS data set, using the values in the first row of the data set as the column headers in the Excel file you will need to do two things:

Code generate a LABEL statement based on the data set
Use the LABEL option when you PROC EXPORT

Example:
data goofy ;
  length a b c $8;
  input a & b & c & ;
  datalines ;
Name 1   Name 2     Name 3
   2        4          6
   3        5          7
;

* compute labels for label statement ;
data _null_ ;
  set goofy (obs=1) ;
  length _name_ $32 ;
  length labels $32767 ;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 ;
    call vnext(_name_) ;
    if _name_ = '_name_' then leave ;
    labels = catx(' ', labels, catx('=', _name_, quote(trim(vvaluex(_name_))))) ;
  end ;
  call symputx('labels',labels) ;
  put 'NOTE: Computed ' labels= ;
run ;

* pre delete the output so we get a fresh Excel file;
* If not done you might be replacing a worksheet in an existing workbook ;
filename xlout "want.xlsx";
%let rc = %sysfunc(fdelete(xlout)) ;

proc export dbms=xlsx label data=goofy(firstobs=2) replace outfile=xlout ;
  label &labels;
run ;



