How to convert first row of a SAS dataset into header
I have a dataset where the row that I need as a header is present as a datarow. I want to convert that first row into header .
Data that I have
         A         B         C 
1      Name    Address      Age
2      John      Carry      66
3      Andy       NYC       32

Data that I want.
        
       Name    Address      Age
1      John      Carry      66
2      Andy       NYC       32


This question is same a the poorly worded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78927242/how-to-make-first-row-as-the-header-while-importing-an-excel-xlsm-file-into-sa. See my answer there

Do you want to make a new DATASET? Or something else.  If something else then please explain clearly what you want to create.  Note: If your want to share a description of a SAS dataset the clearest way is to share SAS code that creates it.  Then the types and lengths of variables are all clear, unlike in a listing.

Pull out the names from the first observation.  A simple way is to use OBS=1 dataset option and PROC TRANSPOSE.
proc transpose data=have(obs=1) out=names;
  var _all_;
run;

Now use them to create OLD=NEW pairs.
proc sql noprint;
select catx('=',nliteral(_name_),nliteral(col1))
    into :renames separated by ' '
  from names 
  where upcase(_name_) ne upcase(col1)
;
quit;

Then use those pairs to generate a RENAME statement (or RENAME= dataset option).  use FIRSTOBS=2 to skip over the observation with the names.
data want;
  set have(firstobs=2);
  rename &renames;
run;


try the following:
DATA A0 a1 a2;
input A $4. B $8. C $4.;
 if _n_=1 then output a2; else output a1;
 cards;
Name Address Age
John Carry   66
Andy NYC     32
;
run;
%macro nms;
proc sql; 
 select count(name) into :n from sashelp.vcolumn where libname='WORK' and             memname='A2';
 %let n=&n.;
 select name into :nm1 - :nm&n.  from sashelp.vcolumn where libname='WORK' and     memname='A2';
 select &nm1. %do i=1 %to &n.;,&&nm&i.. %end; into :h1 %do j=1 %to &n.; ,:h&j.     %end;  from A2;
quit;

data new; set a1; rename %do t=1 %to &n.; &&nm&t.=&&h&t. %end;; run;
%mend;
%nms

